# Changing Keyboard language in on-screen keyboard

Tags: 20.04, onscreen-keyboard

How to change the language of my keyboard in a way that when I enable screen keyboard it should show the keyboard in the language which I selected and not in English via selected language keyboard.

Comment: Please someone answer my question. I'm suffering

Comment: You could use this from terminal `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Settings > Region & Language" where you should see a section called "Input Sources". There, you should be able to add and/or delete keyboard layouts as desired.

- Settings:
  [image: 1]
- Region & Language:
  [image: 2]